# What are the COVID entry requirements into San Marino?

Tags: covid-19, san-marino

I am eying a trip to San Marino, but I can't parse the COVID Requirements of San Marino

The [Foreign Ministry](https://www.esteri.sm/pub2/EsteriSM/en/Covid/Covid.html) site is unhelpful, the UK [FCO](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/san-marino/entry-requirements) has contradicting information and my goverment doesn't have advice for San Marino

I am fully vaccinated (3 doses) with EMA vaccine, so would I need a test to enter San Marino?

Comment: Assume that if you fulfill the conditions for Italy, you will be fine in San Marino. The site states: 'Please note that NO country is currently included in this list.' that require a test, so no test is required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are currently no covid related entry restrictions neither for San Marino nor for Italy (which you have to pass through to get to San Marino).

I am going there next week myself and verified this just a few days ago.

Comment: Theoretically, the OP could use their own plane to [fly into Torraccia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torraccia_airfield) thus entering San Marino without passing through Italy (except by airspace).

Answer (score 2):

I was there 3 weeks ago. At no point was I asked to, or even given the opportunity to, document my COVID status. I stayed at hotel, went to a restaurant, and attended a sporting event.